# Comparing lists - Homework Python

Tags: list, python-3.x, compare

```
 correct_ans = ['B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', \
               'D', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A']
```

here is my statement to import the list from txt file

```
 # import user answers into a list
 infile = open('testscores.txt', 'r')
 driver_ans = infile.readlines()
 infile.close()

 driver_ans = ['B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', \
               'D', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A']

    for index in range(0, 20):
         if driver_ans[index] == correct_ans[index]:
             total_correct += 1
         else:
             wrong_ans.append(index + 1)
```

This logic continues to return that all are wrong answers.  This is not correct comparing visually my "correct_ans" list and my "driver_ans" list.  What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: That depends. What's the rest of your code look like? We don't know what is inside `driver_ans` or `correct_ans`.

Comment: Could you show as the values for driver_ans and correct_ans

Comment: @hyperboreus I have updated and included my list content

Comment: First you read driver_ans from a file and then you set it manually? What format does testscores.txt have? One answer per line? If this is the case, keep in mind that your answers read from the file will end in a newline character and hence all we be wrong, as `'A\n' != 'A'`.

Comment: @hyperboreus: that was exactly the problem, I have stripped the \n and it is working fine!  Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only guessing. If testscores.txt has the content

```
B
D
A
A
...
```

keep in mind, that driver_ans will be

```
['B\n', 'D\n', 'A\n', 'A\n', ...
```

try maybe

```
driver_ans = [x.strip ('\n') for x in infile.readlines()]
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was looking in the wrong place...  I didn't .rstrip the \n character.  I corrected this and you're correct!  I is working perfectly!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The `readlines()` function returns lines that *include* the trailing newline. So, try:

```
driver_ans = [x.strip() for x in infile.readlines()]
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was the problem, once I was pointed in the direction that wasn't my if/else logic I saw my error!